# Add a line of code after the first <?php line

Tags: php, linux, perl

I need to update a website that is moving to a new host. I would like to add the following line to each file, only once, after the first occurrence of `<?php`:

```
define('FRAMEWORK_LOCATION', '/home/someUser/framework.php');
```

I have tried several variations of this Perl oneliner:

```
$ find . -name '*' -print0 | xargs -0 perl -pi -e 's|<?php|<?php\rdefine('\''FRAMEWORK_LOCATION'\'', '/home/someUser/framework.php');'
```

However, as can be seen it would affect all lines. I am not particularly concerned about the case of additional code after the initial `<?php` though if a solution does take that into account then that would be good for me to learn from as well.

Comment: A suggestion: You might like to put that define() in a config.php, then include that file from the others. You get flexibility in the future this way.

Comment: @HappyTimeGopher: No, I would not get any more flexibility because I would still need to update the line that include() the config.php file. If either line changes, it is a simpler Perl script to update the existing line.

Comment: @dotancohen no happy is right. Next time you need to change that FRAMEWORK_LOCATION, you'll only need to do it in one place rather than in every file.

Comment: That is irrelevant: he is discussing a PHP best practice while this question is about a Perl script for manipulating PHP. I appreciate the advice but I don't want to take this question offtopic.

Comment: Classic example on how to *not* write your code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly use sed, without invoking perl:

```
$ find . -name '*' -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sed -e '0,/<?php/s||&\ndefine("FRAMEWORK_LOCATION","/home/someUser/framework.php")|'
```

The relevant bit is:

```
sed -e '0,/<?php/s||&\nNEW_TEXT|'
```

where you are specifying:

1. the range `0,/<?php`: from the first line to the first occurrence of `<?php`
2. the substitution `s||&\nNEW_TEXT|`: where you substitute the previous match `<?php` with itself followed by a new line with some new text.

Note that I added the switch `-type f` to `find` for filtering out directories.

Comment: Thank you! I did have to make some changes, but this one-liner was the closest to get me to the final goal.

Comment: For googlers who happen upon this post: `find . -name \*.php -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i '0,/<?php/s||<?php\ndefine("FRAMEWORK_LOCATION","/home/someUser/framework.php");\n|'`

Answer (score 2):

```
perl -ie 'undef $/; $txt = <>; $txt =~ s|<?php|<?php\rdefine("FRAMEWORK_LOCATION", "/home/someUser/framework.php")|; print $txt;'
```

or

```
perl -ie '$first = 1; while (<>) { if ($first && s|<?php|<?php\rdefine("FRAMEWORK_LOCATION", "/home/someUser/framework.php")|) { $first= 0; } print; }'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
find . -name "*" -print0 | xargs -0 sed '0,/<?php/s/<?php/<?php\n\tdefine(...)/'
```